# How can I enable a resource file to pick up enivronment variables like application.properties does in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a resource file in spring that I want to be populated with environment variable, similar to how spring sets up application properties on startup. In application.properties I have something like this

`app.foo.enabled=${app_foo_enabled}`

In my environment variables in .bashrc file I have

`export app_foo_enabled=false`

On Startup the "app.foo.enabled" property takes the value false.
How do I enable this for other files in my resource folder in my spring app.

My approach currently is to do file manipulation..but I am looking for a more direct way.

Comment: The idea of having one application.properties file is to have a single point where all properties are defined. If you are having multiple properties files this advantage is lost so you can simply use properties without gathering them in a property file.

Comment: Why do you want to "populate a file with environment variable"?

Comment: @Smutje I have a resource file which is being used in my application for a different purpose than apllication.properties. There are placeholders in that file which I want to replace by environment variables.